# Chef Server 12 | Create User | FQDN to avoid unwanted redirections

Tags: ssl, chef-infra

I am trying to install and configure Chef Server 12 on an CentOS server. I have followed the instructions on the documentation (https://docs.chef.io/server/install_server.html) for the install. However, when I reach the step to create a user, I encounter this error message. Could you help me with this?

```
[root@my-server ~]# chef-server-ctl user-create mukherjeem Mrinal Mukherjee mrinal.mukherjee@whatever mypassword
ERROR: Invalid Redirect: POST request was redirected from https://127.0.0.1/users/ to http://127.0.0.1/en-US/users/. Only GET and HEAD support redirects. Change your server location in knife.rb to the server's FQDN to avoid unwanted redirections.
```

Now, on this CentOS server, I don't have a chef-client installed. Hence, I don't think I have the 'knife' command available to me. The documentation doesn't suggest I install a chef-client on this server either. The error seems to be something to do with SSL certificates. What am I missing?

Comment: how does `knife.rb` file look like? and are you sure you are using default location for it? also check your `hostname`.

Comment: I dont have a knife.rb. At least, not that I know of. I did a simple rpm install of the chef server. Just so that it helps, I have a CentOS 7 server. I'm sorry, what do I need to check in the hostname?

Comment: Don't you have another apache or nginx installed on your box before the chef-server install, the behavior let me think there's an apache2 running on port 443, blocking the chef-server nginx to use this port ? do a `chef-server-ctl status` to ensure all services are up and running. And the chef-server itself use chef client to configure/reconfigure, you have a knife command available and it's what is called under the hood with chef-server-ctl for some operations.